java.util.HashMap and java.time.Duration not valid POJO Types for Flink
I have this hint in the logs of the my Flink 1.15 app for 'java.time.Duration' and 'java.util.HashMap':
Class class <*> cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.
Is there a Flink compatible class for Duration and HashMap?

Hashmaps should be supported via Flink's native, built-in serialization processes as they are some of the more commonly used data structures. Duration on the other hand wouldn't fall under the same umbrella and might require some tinkering through either:

Consider a native, serializable representation of the Duration (e.g. epoch millis, etc.) and storing that instead of the Duration object.
Consider implementing a custom serializer to have finer-grained control over the serialization of the Duration object (see related docs).

Another common miss is to ensure that the class that you are attempting to serialize implements the Serializable interface. It may seem like an obvious thing, but I've found it is required:
class YourClass : Serializable {}

The related documentation for POJO serialization can be extremely useful to ensure that your class is checking all of the appropriate boxes and the following rules:

The class must be public.
It must have a public constructor without arguments (default constructor).
All fields are either public or must be accessible through getter and setter functions. For a field called foo the getter and setter methods must be named getFoo() and setFoo().
The type of a field must be supported by a registered serializer.


This is from my logs:
Class class java.util.HashMap cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.
So maybe it's a bug.

Can you post what your class looks like? It’s possible one of the inner classes used in the hashmap doesn’t have a supported serializer which would need to be defined/hinted to Flink.
